# Cloning project from Github fails

Tags: android

When I clone an Android project from GitHub the following error appears:

"Gradle sync failed: Could not download protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:25.2.3): No cached version available for offline mode            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

How do I solve it?

Comment: are you online at all? have working internet connection? maybe you forgot to configure proxy if you are behind it.

Comment: yes i am online at all

Answer (score 1):

While looking in to the maven repo, I can not see the version you specified. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.analytics-library/protos 
Try

- protos:25.2.0

OR

- protos:25.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can download jar file from here
https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.tools.analytics-library%22

the version you have specified in gradle line is not available on maven repository so it will throw error when you sync your project.